# Convert Mysql Query to Rails ActiveRecord Query Without using find_by_sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have table named questions like follows

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| id | title                                                   | category |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 89 | Tinker or work with your hands?                         |        2 |
| 54 | Sketch, draw, paint?                                    |        3 |
| 53 | Express yourself clearly?                               |        4 |
| 77 | Keep accurate records?                                  |        6 |
| 32 | Efficient?                                              |        6 |
| 52 | Make original crafts, dinners, school or work projects? |        3 |
| 70 | Be elected to office or make your opinions heard?       |        5 |
| 78 | Take photographs?                                       |        3 |
| 84 | Start your own political campaign?                      |        5 |
|  9 | Free spirit or a rebel?                                 |        3 |
| 38 | Lead a group?                                           |        5 |
| 71 | Work in groups?                                         |        4 |
|  2 | Helpful?                                                |        4 |
|  4 | Mechanical?                                             |        6 |
| 14 | Responsible?                                            |        6 |
| 66 | Pitch a tent, an idea?                                  |        1 |
| 62 | Write useful business letters?                          |        5 |
| 28 | Creative?                                               |        3 |
| 68 | Perform experiments?                                    |        2 |
| 10 | Like to figure things out?                              |        2 |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

I have a sql query to get one random record from each category.Can any one convert the mysql query to rails activerecord query(with out using `Question.find_by_sql`).This mysql query is working absolutely fine but I need only active record query because of my dependency in further steps.

Here is mysql query

```
             SELECT t.id, title as question, category
                FROM
              (
                SELECT 
                (
                  SELECT id
                    FROM questions
                   WHERE category = t.category
                   ORDER BY RAND()
                   LIMIT 1
                ) id
                  FROM questions t
                 GROUP BY category
              ) q JOIN questions t
                  ON q.id = t.id
```

Thank You for your consideration!

Comment: Appreciated your response.I have n categories and I need a question from each category

Comment: Sorry didn't read the question properly!

Answer (score 1):

When things get crazy one have to reach out for [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel):

> It is intended to be a framework framework; that is, you can build
>   your own ORM with it, focusing on innovative object and collection
>   modeling as opposed to database compatibility and query generation.

So what we want to do is to let Arel create the query for us. Moreover the approach [here](http://push-hard.blogspot.de/2009/11/mysql-select-random-row-from-each-group.html) is gonna be used: the `questions` table is left joined with randomized version of itself:

```ruby
q_normal = Arel::Table.new("questions")
q_random = Arel::Table.new("questions").project(Arel.sql("*")).order("RAND()").as("q2")
```

Time to left join

```ruby
query = q_normal.join(q_random, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(q_normal[:category].eq(q_random[:category])).group(q_normal[:category]).order(q_random[:category])
```

Now you can use which columns you want using `project`, e.g.:

```ruby
query.project(q_normal[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to do this requires a good bit of application code. I don't think there's a way of accessing the `RAND()` functionality in MySQL (or equivalent in other DB technologies) using ActiveRecord. Here's what I came up with:

```
counts = Question.group(:category_id).count(:id)
offsets = {}
counts.each do |cat_id, count|
  offsets[cat_id] = rand(count)
end
random_questions = []
offsets.each do |cat_id, offset|
  random_questions.push(Question.where(:category_id => cat_id).offset(offset).first)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . But this is not satisfied my requirements. Actually I want that mysql query to convert active record query with out using find_by_sql . Please refer once again my question . Finally We need only active record query .